# Increase the base device size of docker container with Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster setup with 3 worker nodes and a master node. Using docker images to generate pods and altering the working containers. I have been working on one image and have altered it heavily to make the servers within work. The problem I am facing is -

> There is no space on the device left.

On further investigation, I found the docker container is set at a 10G size limit which now, I would definitely want to change. How can I change that without losing all my changes in the container and without the need of storing the changes as a separate image altogether?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the limit without a restart is impossible.

To prevent data loss during the container restart, you can use [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) and store data there, instead of the root image.

P.S. It is not possible to mount [Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) dynamically to a container without restart.